# Sublime text plugin: Scrolling selected region to top of window

Tags: sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

Here's what I have working so far, which finds a region starting with **/* Output:** to the end of the file, then displays that region in the window.

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin

class ShowJavaExampleOutput(sublime_plugin.EventListener):
    def on_load(self, view):
        if view.file_name().endswith(".java"):
            output_region = view.find(r"/\* Output:.*", 0)
            if output_region:
                view.show(output_region)
```

This works, but I'd like the line containing **/* Output:** to always appear at the top of the window. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: This makes the line containing /* Output to appear at the top of the view. I don't understand what you want. Do you want that the line is at the top even if you later scroll down to other positions?

Comment: Actually what it does is make the end of the output_region appear at the bottom of the view. What I would like to do is make the top of output_region be at the top of the view.

Comment: For me it appears at the top of the view (not at the bottom). Version info: sublime text 3 build 3083 on linux mint.